# Error [0] error crashes my code halfway the testing using selenium

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

`Selenium Webdriver JS` **crashes** my short script halfway due to the `unexpected alert open error`.

Anyone has a clue on how to **resolve** this issue? Would it be also due to my own `code`?

Kindly help me **investigate** my `code` below. It crashed on the `8th iteration, company.name` line. Although on my other compilations, it crashes on other iterations.

```
var companies = [];

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4000);

driver.get('http://edge.pse.com.ph/companyDirectory/form.do');

driver.wait(until.titleIs('Company List'), 1000);

var parent = driver.getWindowHandle();

var count = 1;

while (count < 7) {
    //This will click on each element
    for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
        driver.sleep(1000);
        var company = new Object();
        company.name = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="dataList"]/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[1]/a')).getText();
        company.ticker = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="dataList"]/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[2]/a')).getText();
        company.sector = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="dataList"]/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[4]')).getText();
        company.listingdate = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="dataList"]/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[5]')).getText();

        var element = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="dataList"]/table/tbody/tr[' + i + ']/td[1]/a'));
        driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

        company.outstandingshares = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="contents"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')).getText();

        company.price = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="contents"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')).getText();
        driver.navigate().back();
        companies.push(company);
    }

    count++;
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("'" + count + "'")).click();
}
```

Comment: From the error, at some point you're getting a JS alert. If you're expecting this you an handle it in the normal selenium way, but if you're not, you'll have to see if some part of your script isn't functioning properly... going to fast... etc. so you can see what scenario is causing that js alert. I'd suggest having your script take a screenshot on failure so you can see the alert.

Comment: I'd also like to ask about another error if that is ok.. There is specific page that causes a chrome `memory crash` **halfway** on the `for loop`. I tried to access it on a `new chrome window` and it **still crashes**. But when I asked my friend to access the specific site, the page loaded successfully unlike what happened on my end. Do you have an **idea** on what could be the `root cause` of this and workarounds that I could do? Thanks! @mrfreester

Comment: I haven't seen a common case for that, so it's hard to say without more details. You might want to make a new question for that and describe exactly what your loop is doing on the page and post the code and error :)